# Finding the most frequent terms in an index (Error: 400 - all shards failed)

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I indexed over 2.000.000 documents in Elasticsearch (using the library Elastic in R), I want to know the most frequent terms in a particular field, let say, the field is called 'X', containing strings. However, the aggregation function throws an error: Error: 400 - all shards failed

I tried the following in R (examples adjusted from the elastic library manual).

#### Step 1

I firstly created the index, with mapping (i.e., in the original index the 'X' field was indexed as 'keyword' field instead of text', I thought maybe that is the problem.

```
    body <- list(test = list(properties = list(
         X = list(type="text"),
         Y = list(type="long")
         )))
    if (!index_exists("example")) index_create("example")
    mapping_create(index = "example", type = "test", body=body)
```

#### Step 2

I next indexed a bunch of documents

```
    X <- c("xxx first","xxx second","xxx third","yyy fourth")
    Y <- c("21","22","24","17")
    data <- data.frame(X,Y)

    docs_bulk(x=data,index='example',type = "test")
```

#### Step 3

I next created the aggregation query and executed it in r

```
    body <-   
  '{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
   "frequent_tags": {
   "terms": {"field": "X"}
   }
   }
   }
   '

    Search(index='example',body=body)
```

#### Step 4

... and I received the error "Error: 400 - all shards failed"

#### Step 5 and 6

Next I added "attribute." to the the body (i.e. {"field": "attribute.X"}), now the query is executed, but without any results. I also tried {"field": "keyword.X"}), but that did not give the expected results either.

#### Expected result

An object that says

```
xxx --> 3 documents
yyy --> 1 document
first --> 1 document
second --> 1 document
fourth --> 1 document
```

Thank you for your help; let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elastic` maintainer here: first thing when trying to sort out problems on the Elasticsearch side is to do `connect(errors = "complete")` - which will throw the complete Elasticsearch stack trace in your R console when there is one. That should let you know exactly where the problem in your query is.

I followed your example above, with `connect(errors = "complete")` set, and I get:

```r
Search(index='example',body=body)
Error: 400 - all shards failed
ES stack trace:

  type: illegal_argument_exception
  reason: Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on
    [X] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. 
    Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword
    field instead.
```

with

```r
elastic::ping()$version$number
[1] "6.6.1"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @sckott.

I changed the following in **Step 1** and it worked.    `mapping_create("example", type = "test", body = '{ "properties": { "X": { "type": "text", "fielddata": true } } }')`